# How can I show all the selected items within the dropdown box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, caption

In my web application, I have `dropdowncheckboxes` and I need to show the selected items within the `dropdown` box only. I tried my code but I displayed one, two items only. If I select three or four items these items are not showing the `dropdown` box I increased width also but it is not possible to do all scenario's and can anyone suggest me how to do this.

.aspx:

```
 <%@ Register Namespace="Saplin.Controls" Assembly="DropDownCheckBoxes" TagPrefix="asp"  %>

    Insurance:&nbsp;<asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="ddlItems" runat="server" AddJQueryReference="true" UseSelectAllNode="true" UseButtons="true" 
            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlItems_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="drpdwnstyle" ><Texts SelectBoxCaption="" /></asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

my tried code:

```
protected void ddlItems_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<String> checkedList = new List<string>();
    foreach (ListItem item in ddlItems.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            checkedList.Add(item.Value);
        }
     }            
     ddlItems.Texts.SelectBoxCaption = String.Join(",", checkedList.ToArray());
}
```

[My result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndIk3.png)

Comment: I am understanding your issue correctly you're able to select items and they go into an array that then DO display? but if the name is larger \ span wider than the select element they don't show?

Comment: Hi Simon price, Thank you, select larger name items they are not show in dropdownbox.

Comment: What is the behaviour that you were expecting \ wanting? You may be tackling this from the wrong approach

Comment: Can you please see this my result image i placed at last how it will show items

Comment: Looks like the width is not enough? I see Aenta in the dropdown but in the array it is Aenta Better Health.....

Comment: Hi, your saying correctly but when i increase the width for 3 selected items it will shows fine when i set width a particular figure and i need to select another item these items also showing like not enough space.every time when i select items it is not possible to change width again and again

Comment: I think it is possible to set a `max-width` on the dropdown.

Comment: `max-width` property is not there in my dropdowncheckboxes control. can  you provide another way to do this.

Comment: `CssClass` contains a class in your css? You can put the `max-width` on `drpdwnstyle` class.

Comment: Is it possible to show tooltip when i place the cursor on the dropdowncheckboxes box it will possible to show all selected items can you please tell me

Comment: IF you are comfortable with using Select2, it is very good component. I personally recommended it

Comment: Thank you, i am newer about this custom control.but i don't know about that i googled but i am not understanding can you please tell me  how can i use it

Comment: how can i mouse over my dropdown i need to see all items